# In XAML: Stop an Event from Taking Place

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a code similar to the one below and a boolean property, in the viewmodel, that I would like to use to control the Loaded event. As an example, if property is false, do not trigger this event. If there was an IsEnabled property in xaml, it would have been easy to bind the boolean property to. In the case of an event, how to accomplish this task?

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}"
                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
</i:EventTrigger>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use [CanExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405761%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) and [RaiseCanExecuteChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommandbase.raisecanexecutechanged%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) methods
   of your [DelegateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.commands.delegatecommand_methods%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) in your view model to check the value
   and effectively disable the DelegateCommand when needed.
2. You can also handle the event in the code behind of the view. Your
   view model is already the data context of the view so accessing it
   from code behind for this purpose is fine and therefore you can
   check the boolean property from your view model and cancel the event
   as needed.